# Session() how upsert from two different table with constraint

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, upsert

How can I upsert using class Session() of sqlalchemy when I have some uniqueconstraint into the tables?
I have this function in pyarchinit_dbmanager.py:

```
def insert_data_session(self, data):
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine, autoflush=False)
        session = Session()
        session.add(data)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

And the code in pyarchinit_Config.py:

```
    if mapper_class_write == 'PYUS' :
        
        for sing_rec in range(len(data_list_toimp)):
            
            try:
                data = self.DB_MANAGER_write.insert_pyus(
                    self.DB_MANAGER_write.max_num_id(mapper_class_write,
                                                     id_table_class_mapper_conv_dict[mapper_class_write]) + 1,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].area_s,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].scavo_s,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].us_s,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].stratigraph_index_us,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].tipo_us_s,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].rilievo_originale,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].disegnatore,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].data,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].tipo_doc,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].nome_doc,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].coord,
                    data_list_toimp[sing_rec].the_geom)
                    
               
                self.DB_MANAGER_write.insert_data_session(data)
                
                value = (float(sing_rec)/float(len(data_list_toimp)))*100
                self.progress_bar.setValue(value)
                
                QApplication.processEvents()
                
            except Exception as e :
                
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Errore", "Error ! \n"+ str(e),  QMessageBox.Ok)
                return 0
```

area_s, scavo_s, and us_s are the unique constraint.

So if I want to import the data without conclict it is OK but if I want to ignore the duplicate but just insert new data I have the problem with unique contraint.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I solved like that:

```
 from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
 from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

 @compiles(Insert)
 def _prefix_insert_with_ignore(insert, compiler, **kw):
     return compiler.visit_insert(insert.prefix_with('OR IGNORE'), *kw)

 def insert_data_session(self, data):
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine, autoflush=False)
    session = Session()
    session.add(data)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

So I can skip the uniqconstarint and add new data and ignore the others.